# Почему система думает что navigationbar всегда отсутствует?

Tags: android, navigationbar

Получаю высоту navigationbar таким вот образом.

```
public static int getNavGarHeight(final Context context)
    {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0 && hasNavBar(resources))
        {
            return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private static boolean hasNavBar(Resources resources)
    {
        int id = resources.getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android");
        boolean has = false;
        if (id > 0)
            has = resources.getBoolean(id);
        return has;
    }
```

Но всегда возвращается 0, путем дебага, выяснил, что hasNavBar всегда возвращает false.  Хотя navigationbar точно есть.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (id > 0)
```

не нужно. [resources.getBoolean(id)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getBoolean%28int%29)вернёт true, только если id не ноль.

`resources.getIdentifier()` не находит "config_showNavigationBar",
скорее всего, [неправильно указали параметры.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)